# Super villain with handlebar moustache and super strength

Tags: marvel, dc, comics, character-identification

I'm trying to figure out the name of this super villain, here is what I remember:

- Super strength (yawn)
- Looks like he could be somebody's dad (he had a really nice looking sweatshirt, and I think a handlebar moustache?)
- Was a *very nice* guy (this one time he stole from an armored car, but then gave the armored car drivers all the money when he found out his actions were going to get them fired)
- I'm pretty sure he got killed off in space somehow, so he hasn't had any recent appearances to my knowledge
- He's supposed to be based on a real person
- I'm 95% sure he's Marvel but he might be DC

He's my favorite joke villain but I can't remember his name; does anyone know who this is?

Comment: Was this an older comic (60s, 70's, 80's?) or something more recent?

Comment: I feel like he was introduced during the silver age of comics and killed off sometime in the last decade.  He's a very minor character though (think paste pot pete but less well known).

Comment: Can you remember who was this villain fighting (if you name some heroes we'll know if he was really Marvel/DC, or someone could locate the story)? Can you remember anything he did in any of his stories (like memorable fights or something)?

Comment: @Deion The most memorable thing I can remember was the armored car heist.  He is stealing the money out from the back of the car, and the driver says something like "Oh gee, I'm really gonna get fired for this" and he hands him a stack of money and apologises for not being more considerate.  Then every other security gaurd in the car makes up an increasingly bad excuse as to why they need money and he leaves empty handed (I think he might have given them his spare change too).  He died in space due to some portal getting destroyed I think.  That's all I got.

Comment: He sounds like the kind of throw-away villain that was always present in only one issue of the silver age comics. He shows up, he gets defeated by our hero, end of story. Was this such a one-off?

Comment: He showed up at least twice (because I know he died in a comic) several years apart, but yeah.  He was mostly a throw away character.

Comment: The only sweatshirt I can think of is the one Sandman used to wear with the stripes.

Comment: I'd say [*Turner D Century*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turner_D._Century), except he doesn't have super-strength, and he doesn't wear a sweatshirt. He was killed by Scourge in the late 1980s (*Captain America* #319), but was resurrected as some sort of clone later; it's possible some later death was in space. The incident with the armored car would not be completely out of character, especially if one of the guards was older.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [**Batroc the Leaper**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batroc_the_Leaper)? He fits the mustache description

[image]
[image]

There is also another guy in the Marvel Universe with a nice mustache, but he is not a villain. He is [Dum Dum Dugan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dum_Dum_Dugan):

[image]

Comment: No he looked 100% like a regular guy.  He always had a very normal looking sweatshirt on. (also Batroc had no super strength).

Comment: You mean like a hooded sweatshirt?